# Webscraping wikipedia and trying to produce a graph but cant convert values to numeric

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to extract code from a wikipedia page, specifically a table and then create a graph using the scraped values.

```
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Otago#Admissions"
selector <- "#mw-content-text > div.mw-parser-output > table:nth-child(63)"

web_page <- read_html(url)
raw_table <- html_node(web_page, selector)
processed_table <- html_table(raw_table, fill=TRUE)

processed_table_tibble <- as_tibble(processed_table)

processed_table_tibble <- processed_table_tibble %>% 
  select(degrees = `Enrolment By Qualification Type[39]`, 2:6) %>% 
  filter(degrees == "Doctoral" | degrees == "Masters'")

processed_table_tibble <- processed_table_tibble %>% 
  pivot_longer(c("2015","2016","2017","2018","2019"), names_to = "year", values_to = "count")

processed_table_tibble %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = count, fill = degrees)) +
  geom_histogram(position = "dodge", stat="identity") +
  labs(title = "Counts of doctoral and masters' students at Otago", x = "year", y = "counts") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")    
  #scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 1600))
```

My main issue is that I can create the graph how it should look with the exception of the y axis. The y axis should start at 0 and have I think they're called breaks (the numbers on the y axis) every 500 up to 1500 and then have no more. I have come to the realization that the count values are not numeric which is I think the reason for the issue.  I would like the y axis breaks? to be 0, 500, 1000, and 1500. I tried `scale_y_continuous()` but the y axis values aren't numeric so that doesnt work. I have tried many other ways to convert it but all result in NA's for my count vector. Or going by how I've been taught I try to convert the columns using `mutate()`(eg = `as.numeric()`) and it just results in `unexpected = in mutate` error.

When I first scrape the table it results in the column names being the years so I `pivot_longer()` to change that. But we have been taught to name the columns after scraping the data and then use the `mutate()` to convert to numeric but as mentioned it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Your count column has a comma. That's a no-go.

Try this

```
processed_table_tibble %>% 
  mutate(count = gsub(count, pattern = ",", replacement = "") %>% as.numeric())
```

so:

```
processed_table_tibble %>% 
  ###add this line
  mutate(count = gsub(count, pattern = ",", replacement = "") %>% as.numeric()) %>%  
  ###
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = count, fill = degrees)) +
  geom_histogram(position = "dodge", stat="identity") +
  labs(title = "Counts of doctoral and masters' students at Otago", x = "year", y = "counts") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

Comment: Thats awesome, that explains why. I didnt even think about the commas being an issue. Is there anyway I could remove the commas using str_replace or something along the lines of that?

Comment: @LetsCode Of course. Just make sure you use ```str_replace_all``` instead of ```str_replace``` because there may be many commas. The ```sub/gsub``` does the same as ```str_replace / str_replace_all``` though.

Comment: Thanks again, its feels like Im on the right track most of the time just a single function is wrong or something small is going ignored. Cheers

Comment: @LetsCode Cheers! Glad it helped, consider accepting the answer